# Many "empty" sessions with NULL princial_name

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

I use spring-session-jdbc with spring-security. At this moment I have logged 20 users (with correct session id and principal_name) and about 11k rows with session-id and empty principal_name. Is it a normal behavior? My settings:

security.sessions= (Default)

@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 86400)

Comment: Please provide some additional details about your app - which version of Spring Session and which RDBMS are you using? Additionally, set the `org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` log level to `DEBUG` and verify that `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository#cleanUpExpiredSessions` logs every minute something like _Cleaned up N expired sessions_.

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.9

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.9, spring-session-jdbc:1.3.3, Percona cluster 5.6 (4 nodes).  cleanUpExpiredSessions works correct, because all sessions have LAST_ACCESS_TIME in the range of (86400 > (current_time - LAST_ACCESS_TIME) / 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything abnormal by itself with having a big number of session records in the database, especially since you've verified that clean up of expired sessions works OK.

You have configured a fairly big `maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds` of 86400 seconds (1 day) so it isn't unreasonable to have that number of anonymous sessions (i.e. unauthenticated sessions, or session records with no `principal_name` set) initiated over the period of one day.

Comment: I found issue in my code... In AuthController I have custom logout action. In this action SecurityContextHolder was incorrect cleared and the session wasn't deleted.